# Let $A \in M(n,n,F)$ be upper triangular. Show that $\dim(\ker(A)) \leq$ no of zeros on the diagonal

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $F$ be a field. Let $A \in \operatorname{M}_{n,n}\left(F\right)$ be an upper-triangular matrix. Show that $\dim\left(\ker A\right)$ is less than or equal to the number of zeroes on the diagonal of $A$.

My answer is:
Let $A=(a_{i,j})_{i,j}$ where $a_{i,j}=0$ $\forall j >i$

Now for each $a_{i,i} \neq 0$ (with $1 \leq i \leq n$) 
We can make that corresponding $i$ th column zero except $(i,i)$ th position. So that corresponding $i$th row will linearly independent in the row space of $A$.

Hence $dim(Im(A)) \geq |\{a_{ii}|a_{ii} \neq 0 \}|$.

By Rank-Nullity Theorem, $\dim(\ker(A)) \leq$ no of zeros on the diagonal.

Now I am interested any other solution.. Other simple solution will be well enough.

Comment: One alternative approach is to pick the submatrix formed by the rows and the columns corresponding to those $i$ for which $a_{i, i} \neq 0$. This submatrix is upper-triangular and has nonzero entries on the diagonal; thus, it is invertible.

Comment: The determinant of $A-\lambda I$ is equal to $(-1)^k\lambda^k\cdot \prod(a_{i_si_s}-\lambda), s=1,2...,n-k $. So  $\lambda=0$ is $k-$ times root of the characteristic polynomial and the dimension of the span of the eigenvectors coresponding to $\lambda=0$  is at most the number of times $\lambda=0$ is a root, i.e $dim Ker(A)\leq k$

Comment: But what I suggested has some flaws and is not very rigorous.